# Why is this jQuery Ajax request failing?

Tags: ajax, jquery

The [FCC](http://www.fcc.gov/) recently made available a small [set of API calls to access FCC data](http://reboot.fcc.gov/developer/).  In particular, I'm interested in the [Consumer Broadband Test API](http://reboot.fcc.gov/developer/consumer-broadband-test-api).  I'm trying to access this API through jQuery but am failing.  Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong with my code or if this seems to be a problem with FCC's API.

If you visit this API request in a browser, it returns a XML response just fine: http://data.fcc.gov/api/speedtest/find?latitude=30.240236062827297&longitude=-97.64787337499999

So I've tried to load this data in jQuery using various methods:

```
var url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/speedtest/find?latitude=30.240236062827297&longitude=-97.64787337499999";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("ajax: " + data);
    }
});

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log("getJSON: " + data);
});

$.get(url, function(data) {
    console.log("get: " + data);
});
```

In the Firebug console, all three requests show a 200 (OK) status, but the response body is empty.  Also, the resulting `console.log` messages are:

```
ajax: 
getJSON: null
get:
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I didn't think is was possible to do a cross domain ajax request. You might have to do something like this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work around the Same Origin Policy, you'll need to use JSONP. [It is supported](http://reboot.fcc.gov/developer/consumer-broadband-test-api) by the API. Add `callback=?` to the URL string in your `.getJSON()` call:

> If the URL includes the string
>   "callback=?" in the URL, the request
>   is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in
>   $.ajax() for more details.

So, something like this:

```
var url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/speedtest/find?...&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  // do stuff
});
```

References: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!  I had to use jsoncallback rather than callback, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make cross-domain calls using AJAX. It doesn't work like that.

What you probably want to do is to have your AJAX query URL be a local script on your own server, then have that script run a request for the API url (using cURL or something).